# Check value prior to form submit in POST controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if the subject is inaccurate, but basically upon submit of a Form I want to compare the previous value of the model's Foreign Key.

My model is:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Store")]
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    public string BookedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateBooked { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

After editing a booking in Edit view and submitting, I want to check if the StoreID has been modified, so that I can perform a required action.

I was creating an instance of Booking as oldBooking and then comparing `StoreID` with `booking.StoreID` passed back from View, but this created an Attach error when I saved the Edited form.

Any suggestions?

Edited 27/1/15:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,StoreID,BookedBy,DateBooked,Agreement,Description,FromDate,ToDate")] Booking booking, string returnURL)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Booking oldBooking = db.Bookings.Find(booking.ID);
    int prevStoreID = oldBooking.StoreID;
    db.Entry(booking).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    if(prevStoreID == booking.StoreID)
    {
      sendStoreChangeEmail(prevStoreID, booking.StoreID);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", null);
  }
  ViewBag.StoreID = new SelectList(db.Stores, "ID", "ID", booking.StoreID);
  return View(booking);
}
```

When attempt to update db entry state I get this error:

> "Attaching an entity of type 'uatlab2.Models.Booking' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate."

Comment: In the POST method, just get the original `Booking` from the database and compare the `StoreID` values

Comment: That's what I do:
                Booking oldBooking = db.Bookings.Find(booking.ID);
                int prevStoreID = oldBooking.StoreID;
                
                db.Entry(booking).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                if (prevStoreID == booking.StoreID)
                    sendStoreChangeEmail(prevStoreID, bookingStoreID);

but when I try to save modified booking it gives following error:
"Attaching an entity of type 'uatlab2.Models.Booking' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value."

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit you question with the additional code (too difficult to read in comments especially when you don't format it!)

Comment: And you cant use `ViewBag.StoreID = ....`. You already have a model property named `StoreID` so binding will fail! And there is no point adding the last parameter of the `SelectList` constructor since your binding to a property (its ignored by the html helper)

Comment: ViewBag.StoreID and the Bind(StoreID...) do not cause any error if the oldBooking is removed.

It seems to be that there are 2 calls to the Bookings db table open at the same time. Can I dispose of oldBooking once I have prevStoreID?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a couple of other posts and googling 'detach', i read this article:
[ASP MVC How to update DB entry with collections field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020518/asp-mvc-how-to-update-db-entry-with-collections-field)

and after I have got prevStoreID do this:
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Detach(oldBooking);

And it works.

Thanks for your help and inspiration.

C